# Perform action after label is updated in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using a pin screen for login to my app. The pin screen consists of four labels and a hidden text field. When the user enters text via the keypad, I update the labels with a symbol. This works fine, except that the last label does not get actually get updated before login begins, and remains empty while the login process is completed.

These are the relevant bits of code:

```
//an observer has been added elsewhere
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    UITextField *field = [notification object];
if (field == inputField) 
    {
    NSString *newText = field.text;     
    if ([newText length] <= pinLength) [self updatePINDisplay];
    }
}


-(void)updatePINDisplay 
{
    if ([pinText length] > pinLength) return;

    for (NSInteger ii = 0; ii < [pinText length]; ii++)
    {
        UILabel *label = [pinFields objectAtIndex:ii];
        [label setText:@"x"];
    }

    for (NSInteger ii = [pinText length]; ii < pinLength; ii++)
    {
    UILabel *label = [pinFields objectAtIndex:ii];
    [label setText:[NSString string]];
    }

    if ([pinText length] == pinLength) [self login];
}
```

The problem arises because [self login] launches other processes which happen before the last pin label is updated, so the login occurs while the last box is still empty.

I have worked around the problem by replacing

```
[self login]
```

with

```
[self performSelector:@selector(login) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1]
```

but I don't like the arbitrary time delay. I was hoping that maybe there was a delegate method that I could use to launch my login code after the label has been drawn. Something like:

```
-(void)labelDidGetDrawn
```

Any other (non-hack) solution is also welcome:-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like the problem is that the 4th item doesn't get drawn until after the `[self login]` finishes, which is indicative that the login procedure takes some time.    In iOS, drawing doesn't happen immediately, which is why you're only getting the draw if you defer the login until after the OS has an opportunity to update the display.

You have used one reasonable solution here.   Another (arguably less of a hack) is to have your `-[self login]` spawn the login on a separate thread, or at least using an asynchronous mechanism (such as the asynchronous modes of NSURLConnection, assuming you're making a network request).   Then your main thread will quickly return control to iOS and your box will draw.

With Grand Central Dispatch, you could do most of this by having the `-[self login]` place the network code on a background thread, and have the background thread call back to your main thread when complete.   However, this can cause some problems if you want to respond to user events during the login process.

If you can, using `NSURLConnection` asynchronously, and setting up the delegate to report back to you when the operation is complete is probably the best choice, as it gives you the operation to cancel the `NSURLConnection` during the login process if the user requests it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
[label setNeedsDisplay:YES];
if ([pinText length] == pinLength) [self login];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that notification exists, in a way. The label will be drawn during the next iteration of the run loop. So do your `login` at the end of the next run loop iteration, for instance using a `performSelector:afterDelay:0` or maybe using

```
dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^{ [self login]; });
```

But a) this depends on the order of execution of rendering versus timers and dispatch_queues. If rendering happens before timer execution, you're all set.

And b) don't block the main thread. Try to perform the login in a background thread/concurrent queue, or do it asynchronously on the main thread if you're using, e.g., `NSURLConnection`.